# Ubuntu taking long time to boot ,

Tags: boot

I have tried disabling legacy usb , Please let me know  of any solution .
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0U0P

Comment: Please tell us more about your machine. Maybe it is not that fast? How long does the BIOS/EFI shows up? What is the time from GRUB up to the login screen? Or more precise: Define what you understand as long.

Comment: system is running on intel core i3, with 3.2 gb of ram.bios shows for about a minute, from grub to login screen it takes 3 minutes and another 3 minutes to show the desktop.

Comment: How long does the boot from a live CD/USB stick take?

Comment: it takes 1 min to boot.

Comment: How's your partitioning?

Comment: no partitioning present system has just ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Please check your network devices:

```
[   12.491283] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   41.079282] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

Accoring to this some ethernet port is not connected and delays the boot process.